# UIView ignoring my constraints when setting width equal to scrollview?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, autolayout, scrollview

Every time I set the width of my view to my scroll view it pushes the green square off the screen.

[image]

Comment: Seem like your left constraint is not 0, so that's why it is offscreen

Comment: The scrollview is set to 0 for leading and trailing. The uiview is set to 20 for leading and trailing. @qtngo

Comment: I already made sure to uncheck margins @RobertDresler

Comment: You are missing at least one constraint (I see something red above the green square)

Comment: I updated my image for more clarity. It already has top bottom leading and trailing constraints. @J.Doe

Comment: Having a quick look at your constraints: You are saying the view is equal to the center X. After that, you are saying the leading space of the view is equal to the scroll's view leading anchor + 26. That's illegal...

Comment: in your screenshot you've selected the view within the scrollview. Select the scrollview itself and take a screenshot. From the missing constraints error it seems that your scrollview itself doesn't have vertical constraints setup relative to its superview. Also, sometimes storyboard can give you misleading feedback. Can you try just running it and see how it works?

Answer (score 2):

@belgrim I had had a rough time working with scroll views. I would like to share my work around.

1. First, drag a scroll view to your storyboard and pin in to four sides.

[image]

2. Then, add a view inside the scroll view and pin it to the four sides of its superview (i.e. the scroll view)

[image]

3. The result would look like this

[image]
*(Don't worry about the red markers, those will be fixes in the next steps)*

4. Add a constraint to make the view's width equal to its superview's (scrollview) width

[image]

The result would look like:

[image]

5. Now, the most important part, we need to add our content inside the view and should properly define the y-constraints inside the view so that the scroll view scrolls based on the content. Here, I simply, add a label and define the constraints as:

[image]

(Also, I setup the number of lines as 0 and line break as wordwrap)

Finally, we get properly defined storyboard:

[image]

With long text defined in the label outlet, the final output we get:

[image]

I have shown a simple example adding a label, you can add other views as per your need, just make sure that you don't miss defining the y-constraints.

Hope this helps.