# how to can i fix uiscrollview height within safe area

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a problem with uiscrollview's height that is the contentView which is located inside it (uiscrollview) wont be laid out in top and bottom safe area as shown below in photo1 , photo2 take a look please 
the blue area which is displayed that is the scrollview instead of showing contentView there , i've setup my constraints as shown in photo3

[image: photo1]
[image: photo2]
[image: photo3]

so please do you have any idea about it ?
what should i do to solve it ?
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It looks like you should have the ScrollView.top match SafeArea.top and ScrollView.bottom match SafeArea.bottom

Comment: @Yasser Homsi Please go through the steps mentioned in the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621361/uiview-ignoring-my-constraints-when-setting-width-equal-to-scrollview/54625151#54625151
It might be helpful.

Comment: @LorenRogers I wanna make my scrollbar within the status bar area so o have to attach it to SuperView.top instead of attaching it to SafeArea.top